# Building very dense point tileset at zoom16 keeps dropping points for the whole zoom when using tippecanoe

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I'm building a very dense point layer in some tiles (where are few points overlapping or using the same geometries), I want to keep all the points at zoom16 but they keep dropping at zoom 16 and doesn't appear at zoom 17 or 16 in any tile (using Mapbox server to allocate the tileset and being served with Mapbox GL).

I'm using this command to build the tileset which I will be uploading to Mapbox server.

```
tippecanoe --minimum-zoom=13 --maximum-zoom=16 --read-parallel -r1
-B16 --drop-densest-as-needed --coalesce-densest-as-needed --force -l mapbox_data_layer -o output.mbtiles input.geojson
```

The log keeps dropping points from zoom 13 till 15 and then one tile sparsest, but the others seems to be built correctly but at that zoom level doesn't show any of the features overlapping.

Any idea of how to deal with this? I need to show at least at that zoom level all the points, because seems Mapbox doesn't allow you to build bigger that 17 zoom level without special requests. This is an extract of the logs(): everything normal until zoom 16 where all the features should fit.

> 21421807 features, 1771044464 bytes of geometry, 4 bytes of separate
> metadata, 7016918733 bytes of string pool tile 13/4091/2723 size is
> 705432 with detail 12, >500000 Going to try keeping the sparsest
> 63.79% of the features to make it fit tile 13/4091/2724 size is 766206 with detail 12, >500000 Going to try keeping the sparsest 58.73% of
> the features to make it fit tile 13/4092/2724 size is 891261 with
> detail 12, >500000 Going to try keeping the sparsest 50.49% of the
> features to make it fit tile 13/4093/2723 size is 826722 with detail
> 12, >500000 Going to try keeping the sparsest 54.43% of the features
> to make it fit tile 13/4092/2723 size is 978354 with detail 12,
> ........................
>
> 16/32742/21790 size is 602669 with detail 12, >500000 Going to try
> keeping the sparsest 74.67% of the features to make it fit tile
> 16/32743/21791 size is 562731 with detail 12, >500000 Going to try
> keeping the sparsest 79.97% of the features to make it fit tile
> 16/32743/21790 size is 604762 with detail 12, >500000 Going to try
> keeping the sparsest 74.41% of the features to make it fit tile
> 16/32742/21791 size is 573437 with detail 12, >500000

Going to try keeping the sparsest 78.47% of the features to make it fit

I tried adding the -pf and-pk command but when uploading to mapbox server it threw the error of more than 500k features in some tiles...

```
tippecanoe --minimum-zoom=16 --maximum-zoom=16 --read-parallel -r1 -B16 -pk -pf --drop-densest-as-needed --coalesce-densest-as-needed --force
```

Comment: You will need to serve your own vector tiles - there are many examples of vector tile servers for mbtiles on GH, not sure there is another SAAS that serves out pre-built mbtiles files however.